# Should this answer be undeleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

While I was researching grammar induction algorithms, I found [a useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41066357/975097) that had been deleted. Since this answer was deleted by a moderator, I could not vote to undelete it.

Should this answer be undeleted, since it answers the question correctly?

Comment: A better answer should be provided. This is a great opportunity for both a good solid answer and an edit to the question to improve it from simply being a requirements dump.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. That quotation can be contained within an answer, but by itself it makes a very poor answer. Feel free to add a proper answer yourself.

Comment: @KevinB I'm not sure what substantive edits the linked question needs. It's clear, has examples, is narrowly focused, and is on-topic. It may be a "requirement dump" as you put it, but I don't see why that's a problem.

Comment: @cigien The answer included a link that described a solution to the problem, so I'm surprised that it was deleted.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Answers that contain nothing but quotes from an external site (or another answer), are not considered answers, or at least not good answers. There needs to be at least some part of the answer that is written in the user's own words. Answers that don't do that, do often get deleted. That's likely what happened in this case. BTW, while it is recommended that answers contain original content, I don't believe there's an official rule about it, i.e. answers without original content are not *automatically* deleted.

Answer (score 17):

No, we should not undelete that spam/over-promotion. It is one of a string of 46 answers by that user over a few/several days. All of the answers in that string link to the same domain to which the user appears affiliated. While I haven't checked all of the answers, every one which I did check was merely copying & pasting from the website with which they are affiliated. None of the answers I checked disclose their affiliation.

Note: All but one of the answers were deleted prior to me looking at the issue. All of the deleted answers which I looked at were deleted by another moderator in 2016.

Comment: It seems that I was wrong: the link didn't actually answer the question (about the longest non-overlapping subsequence in a string). I should have read it more carefully before trying to undelete it.